# Join multiple tables in D7 Views

Tags: views, database, users

I'm trying to create a View Block to display related information on a node.

I'm creating an image gallery where each image node is tagged with one/more taxonomy terms, and a block on each of those nodes then displays a list of users who have expressed an interest in the same taxonomy term(s).

So the node is tagged with e.g "landscape" and a user has a Profile2 profile in which they have have also selected "landscape" with a taxonomy ref field.

I'm having trouble building the view to achieve this. If I create a new view with a block and select that i'm displaying "Profiles" from the initial dropdown, views seems to remove some of the kinds of objects I can choose in the Contextual Filters or Relationships menus: Node isn't available for linking in a relationship.

If I go about in the "other direction" and make a view of Nodes, then try and create relationships backwards to the Profiles I want, I'm unable to select fields present in the Profile for output - the only fields available are those on the Node.

It seems that by choosing a specific kind of object to list, Views immediately excludes certain possibilities for joining.

Is this not possible? I know what the exact SQL would be, but I'd rather not write a module if a View would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the relationship not go via the taxonomy reference rather than direct profile to node? Or have I misunderstood what you've tried/want to achieve?

Comment: Doh, school-boy error. For some reason I was trying to go directly via the profile direct to the node! Eventual query basically was:

Build a view of profiles, relationship on profile "preferred tags", another relationship on taxonomy, then, another on "content using tag X" then a contextual filter on the current node ID from the URL.

Cheers for the help, bud!

Comment: Welcome! It can certainly be easy at times to lose sight of things behind the UI :-) Glad to help